# How to join/populate 3 tables with Bookshelf in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js

[This is different from already asked question]

I have 3 tables book, chapter, paragraph.

Book related to chapter.(one to many)

Chapter related to Paragraph(one to many)

How can I query Book and get related Chapters and related Paragraph ? Looking for something like nested withRelated

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "book1Info": "",
    "Chapters": [
      {
        "chaptor1Info": "",
        "Paragraphes": [
          {
            "page1": ""
          },
          {
            "page2": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {}
    ]
  },
  {}
]
```

I have read docs and tried *withRelated* without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find it on Bookshelf.js documentation but found something related on github issues page which helped to figure it out-

You can use `withRelated` and provide nested tables with dot.

e.g. -

withRelated: ['Books.Chapters']

OR even

withRelated: ['Books.Chapters.paragraphs']